# Why does implicit conversion not work in accumulate?

Tags: c++, string, templates, implicit-conversion

This is the C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int test_string(const string & str) {
    return str.size();
}

void main() {
    test_string("");                                     //can compile
    vector<string> v;
    string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), "");   //cannot compile
}
```

I want to use implicit conversion from `const char *` to `string` in the call of generic STL function `accumulate`. I know that conversion from `const char *` to string is not explicit, so we can pass `const char *` parameter to calls in which a `string` type is required. This can be proved by the above `test_string` function. But when I did the same thing in `accumulate`, the compiler complain:

> ```
> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *'
> ```

The code works only when I replaced `""` with `string("")`. I don't understand why the implicit conversion works for my custom function but does not work in `accumulate`. Can you explain that? Thanks a lot.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: `void main()` -- No, it should be `int main()`

Comment: "I want to use implicit conversion from const `char *` to `string`"... But the compiler does not know that you "want" that. There's absolutely nothing in expression `accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), "")` to suggest that `""` should be implicitly converted to `std::string`. Why do you expect the compiler to perform the conversion? How do you expect the compiler to figure out that the conversion is necessary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is declared as

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

That means the template argument `T` is deduced from the argument passed in (i.e. `""`). Then it'll be `const char*`. On the other hand, how could the compiler perform the implicit conversion? Which type should be the target type?

You can pass a `std::string` explicitly, or specify the template argument explicitly. e.g.

```
// pass a std::string exactly
string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), string(""));

// T is specified as std::string explicitly
// "" will be implicitly converted to std::string
string sum = accumulate<decltype(v.cbegin()), string>(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), "");
```

Comment: The `string("")` can also be replaced with `""s` in C++11 and beyond

Comment: @Curious: C++14: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: @user5280911 yess

Comment: Thank you, songyuanyao, you precisely caught what my mistake is: I mistakenly thought the type of the third parameter is declared and therefore determined as in a usual function, that's why implicit conversion did not take place.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [possible implementation from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = init + *first;
    }
    return init;
}
```

When you call the function the way you did, `InputIt` will be deduced as a `vector<string>::const_iterator` and `T` will be deduced to be a `const char*`.  As you can see here in the for loop, the line of code that does the "accumulation" is this

```
init = init + *first
```

Here on the right hand side of the assignment `*first` will evaluate to a `string&` and `init` will evaluate to a `const char*`.  Then you will be using the `std::string::operator+` which will concatenate the `const char*` and the `std::string` instance to get a `std::string` back.  And then you are trying to assign a `std::string` to a `const char*` variable.  This is not legal.

This will not work as `std::string` objects **are not implicitly convertible or assignable** to `const char*`, the reverse is true however.

To fix this change your code to the following (note that I postfixed the string literal with a `s`, which is C++14 syntax for a user defined literal (which in this case evaluates to a `std::string`) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    vector<string> v;
    string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), ""s); 
}
```

---

Also as [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581672/why-does-implicit-conversion-not-work-in-accumulate/44581721#comment76151563_44581672), change `void main()` to `int main()`.  For more see [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: This is a very useful answer. My problem is not that I don't know char can't + string, but that I don't understand why the implicit conversion is not triggered. So I did not tick your answer. But I thank you very much for your help and the rich knowledge contained.

Comment: @user5280911 The possible explanation was an attempt to explain why the implicit conversion was not being triggered.  Is there something you did not follow in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why the implicit conversion works for my custom function but does not work in accumulate. Can you explain that?

Implicit conversion isn't even attempted, [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) simply tries to accumulate by adding instances of `std::string` to a sum that's initialized as `auto sum = "";` and you get the same error that you would get in this case:

```
std::string s = "abc";
const char* sum = "";
sum = sum + abc; // <-- error
```

> The code works only when I replaced "" with string("")

Because this way internally accumulator's type is `std::string` and everything works as intended. You may as well do this:

```
string sum = accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), ""s);
```

As a side note, it should be `int main() { ... }`, not `void main`